# unnest() when nulls are stored as empty lists

Tags: r, tidyr

I would like to `unnest()` a data frame where `NULL` values are stored as `list()`.  How can I do it?

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df <-
  tibble::tribble(
    ~date,          ~id,
    '2023-07-21',   1L,
    list(),         140L
  )

df
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>   date          id
#>   <list>     <int>
#> 1 <chr [1]>      1
#> 2 <list [0]>   140

unnest(df, date)
#> Error in `list_unchop()`:
#> ! Can't combine `x[[1]]` <character> and `x[[2]]` <list>.
#> Backtrace:
#>      x
#>   1. +-tidyr::unnest(df, date)
#>   2. +-tidyr:::unnest.data.frame(df, date)
#>   3. | \-tidyr::unchop(...)
#>   4. |   \-tidyr:::df_unchop(...)
#>   5. |     \-vctrs::list_unchop(col, ptype = col_ptype)
#>   6. \-vctrs (local) `<fn>`()
#>   7.   \-vctrs::vec_default_ptype2(...)
#>   8.     +-base::withRestarts(...)
#>   9.     | \-base (local) withOneRestart(expr, restarts[[1L]])
#>  10.     |   \-base (local) doWithOneRestart(return(expr), restart)
#>  11.     \-vctrs::stop_incompatible_type(...)
#>  12.       \-vctrs:::stop_incompatible(...)
#>  13.         \-vctrs:::stop_vctrs(...)
#>  14.           \-rlang::abort(message, class = c(class, "vctrs_error"), ..., call = call)
```

<sup>Created on 2023-10-18 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can replace an empty element with `NA`:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
  mutate(date = lapply(date, function(z) if (!length(z)) NA else z)) %>%
  unnest(date)
# # A tibble: 2 × 2
#   date          id
#   <chr>      <int>
# 1 2023-07-21     1
# 2 NA           140
```

Technically this introduces the logical variant of `NA` (vice what should be a `NA_character_`), but fortunately `unnest(.)` is good enough to cast it correctly when unlisting.

Borrowing from @ThomasIsCoding's excellent answer, we can also use `replace(.)` here:

```r
df %>%
  mutate(date = replace(date, lengths(date) == 0, NA)) %>%
  unnest(date)
```

for the same effect. The benefit is purely speed:

```r
dfbig <- replicate(10000, df, simplify = FALSE) %>%
  bind_rows()
bench::mark(
  lapply = mutate(dfbig, date = lapply(date, function(z) if (!length(z)) NA else z)) %>% unnest(date),
  replace_NA = mutate(dfbig, date = replace(date, lengths(date) == 0, NA)) %>% unnest(date),
  replace_NULL = mutate(dfbig, date = replace(date, lengths(date) == 0, list(NULL))) %>% unnest(date, keep_empty = TRUE),
  within = within(dfbig, date <- unlist(replace(date, !lengths(date), NA_character_), use.names = FALSE))
)
# # A tibble: 4 × 13
#   expression     min  median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result   memory time       gc      
#   <bch:expr> <bch:t> <bch:t>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list>   <list> <list>     <list>  
# 1 lapply      36.8ms 37.22ms      26.8        NA     8.03    10     3      374ms <tibble> <NULL> <bench_tm> <tibble>
# 2 replace_NA 17.96ms 18.42ms      54.3        NA     7.09    23     3      423ms <tibble> <NULL> <bench_tm> <tibble>
# 3 replace_N… 50.75ms 51.47ms      19.4        NA     4.84     8     2      413ms <tibble> <NULL> <bench_tm> <tibble>
# 4 within      1.09ms  1.14ms     867.         NA    11.0    393     5      453ms <tibble> <NULL> <bench_tm> <tibble>
```

Comment: aha, nice comparison! +1 already! Maybe `list(NULL)` needs more effort being transformed to `NA` when `unnest` with `keep_empty = TRUE`.

Comment: That was my thought too (with not enough motivation to actually test that theory) @ThomasIsCoding

Comment: Got [one more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77319406/6574038), please take up in benchmark.

Answer (score 3):

You can try `keep_empty = TRUE`

```
df %>%
    mutate(date = replace(date, lengths(date) == 0, list(NULL))) %>%
    unnest(date, keep_empty = TRUE)
```

or with `NA` in `replace`

```
df %>%
    mutate(date = replace(date, lengths(date) == 0, NA)) %>%
    unnest(date)
```

which gives

```
# A tibble: 2 × 2
  date          id
  <chr>      <int>
1 2023-07-21     1
2 NA           140
```

Comment: Nice! See my recent edit, `NA` is much faster than `list(NULL)`

Answer (score 1):

Using `replace` over negated `lengths` then `unlist` in `within`.

```
> within(df, date <- unlist(replace(date, !lengths(date), NA_character_), u=F))
# A tibble: 4 × 2
  date          id
  <chr>      <int>
1 2023-07-21     1
2 NA           140
3 NA           140
4 2023-07-21     1
```

If you can avoid tibbles, `transform` is slightly faster,

```
> transform(df, date=unlist(replace(date, lengths(date) == 0L, NA_character_), u=F))
        date  id
1 2023-07-21   1
2       <NA> 140
3       <NA> 140
4 2023-07-21   1
```

or, of course data.table

```
> library(data.table)
> setDT(df)[, date := unlist(replace(date, !lengths(date), NA_character_), u=F)]
> df
         date  id
1: 2023-07-21   1
2:       <NA> 140
3:       <NA> 140
4: 2023-07-21   1
```

---

*Data:*

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(date = list("2023-07-21", list(), NULL, "2023-07-21"), 
    id = c(1L, 140L, 140L, 1L)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```